# Changing a field value on beforesubmit

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I've looked all over but can't seem to find how to modify an existing record using Suitescript. Essentially I want to be able to set a field on the record that sets the value of a boolean field based on the value of a different boolean field in the same record

This is my code.

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.0
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
* @NModuleScope Public
*/
var exports = {};

function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
    if (Type = "Expense Report"){
        if (CCC = 1){ 
            record.setFieldValue(Corporate card, 1);
            nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    }}
}

exports.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;


});
```

Comment: This video might help give you some context and direction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kigrT82l7-g

Comment: Here's another video that may help you get a feel for how this sort of thing is done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHg1ER8HmpU